# How to store computed value of a variable from one Python script for reuse again and again in another Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a **python** (3.7.0) script file which takes more than 17,000 text files and then processes each file line by line to fill the required data into a pandas data frame. So the code is like following is the **Script1.py** file:

```
def filePrpcesserFunc(file):
   data = open(file, 'r')
   for line in data.readlines():
      #Does some computing here to get var1, var2, var3
      #var1, var2, var3 are all integers
   return var1, var2, var3

if __name__ == '__main__':
   import glob2
   import pandas
   files = glob2.glob("*.txt")
   #There are more than 17,000 text files to be computed
   X = pandas.DataFrame()
   for file in files:
      rvar1, rvar2, rvar3 = fileProcesserFunc(file)
      X.loc[str(rvar1), str(rvar2)] = rvar3
```

Now the above python script upon runs over 17,000 files to make the pandas dataframe X which needs to be computed only once to get data *(and computation is quite expensive)*. I need to use this dataframe in another script file (say) **Script2.py** to make a Machine Learning model and so to test my model, I would need to access X, again and again, i.e. I would need to run the Script2.py again and again.
Can anyone suggest anything? I would be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the builtin [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module:

In `script1.py`:

```
import pickle
with open('dataframe.txt', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(X, f)
```

In `script2.py`:

```
import pickle
X = pickle.load(open('dataframe.txt', 'rb'))
```

You could also load the built in [to_pickle](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) methods on dataframes:

In `script1.py`:

```
X.to_pickle("./df.pkl")
```

In `script2.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
X = pd.read_pickle(¨./df.pkl¨)
```